# YA fantasy novel about woman seeking revenge on her accuser with the aid of a shapeshifting dragon

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, dragons

I read this book back in middle school, but cannot remember the title. It was a great story, but I can't seem to find it.

The book begins with a woman falsely accused of witchcraft by her neighbor. She is found guilty and is sentenced to be made into an offering for the dragon.

When the dragon finds her, she throws stones at it in a rage. The dragon finds her reaction curious and shapeshifts into a man who agrees to help her seek revenge on her accuser.

Comment: When were you in middle school I.e. when did you read this? Was it new at the time? Why is she falsely accused? What had she done? Or was it a set up? What happens after the dragon helps her? Do they succeed? Etc. You can edit your post to include any extra information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Dragon's Bait* (1992) by Vivian Vande Velde.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/372807.Dragon_s_Bait):

> Fifteen-year-old Alys is not a witch. But that doesn't matter—the villagers think she is and have staked her out on a hillside as a sacrifice to the local dragon. It's late, it's cold, and it's raining, and Alys can think of only one thing—revenge. But first she's got to escape, and even if she does, how can one girl possibly take on an entire town alone? Then the dragon arrives—a dragon that could quite possibly be the perfect ally.

The reviews mention the dragon (Selendrile) being able to change into human form.

---

Found with the Google query `fantasy novel accused witchcraft sacrifice dragon site:goodreads.com/book`.